# Access SQL SumIf Equivalent

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that I am attempting to find how many arrivals at a certain location and group by time frames. ex. 0001-0559, 0600-1159, 1200-1759, and 1800-2359.  My Query SQL is this...

```
SELECT tbl_2_trip_details_2012.arrival_id,
       Hour([tbl_2_trip_details_2012] ! [arrive_ts])    AS [B-Hour],
       Weekday([tbl_2_trip_details_2012] ! [arrive_ts]) AS [A-WeekDay#],
       Month(tbl_2_trip_details_2012 ! arrive_ts)       AS [Month],
       Count(tbl_2_trip_details_2012.trip_id)           AS CountOfTrip_ID

FROM   tbl_2_trip_details_2012

WHERE  (( ( tbl_2_trip_details_2012.arrival_id ) = 84252114 ))

GROUP  BY tbl_2_trip_details_2012.arrival_id,
          Hour([tbl_2_trip_details_2012] ! [arrive_ts]),
          Weekday([tbl_2_trip_details_2012] ! [arrive_ts]),
          Month(tbl_2_trip_details_2012 ! arrive_ts)

HAVING (( ( Month([tbl_2_trip_details_2012] ! [arrive_ts]) ) = 7 ))

ORDER  BY Weekday([tbl_2_trip_details_2012] ! [arrive_ts]),
          Hour(tbl_2_trip_details_2012 ! arrive_ts);
```

The query in this format pulls all of what looks like the information I need. I am having trouble summing the time ranges, by the day of week. I have been trying to do a Sum of the CountOfTrip_ID with "> Or <" in the Criteria field.  I have exhausted the files on Stack, and the Access Help function.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group your hours into 6 hour ranges, just take the integer of hours dived by 6 then multiply the result by 6 again. So it would look like this:

```
int(Hour([tbl_2_trip_details_2012] ! [arrive_ts]) / 6) * 6   AS [Hour-range]
```

You will then get the values of 0, 6, 12, & 18 (the start of each group) which you can group on.

Comment: Tom, I will give this a shot in the morning when I get back to my office.  THanks!

Comment: Tom, I have inserted the code as an Expression and it has worked as you stated.  Thanks!